# Regex to match strings only if in combination

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

i need to match and replace the text in the following ways

if the text is as below, it should not be replaced

> home travel or home visit or home flight - then don't replace

if the text is as below it should be replaced

> travel or visit or flight - replace

I have tried

> (?!(home|parents))(?=(flight|visit|travel))

How can match it in such a way?

Comment: Did you mean to use a lookbehind? `(?<!\bhome )(?<!\bparents )\b(?:flight|visit|travel)\b` https://regex101.com/r/3TJl7M/1

Comment: it definitely does the job.
will need to find  a way to handle cases with extra white spaces between words. Thanks

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: python and golang

Comment: I tried it this way, modifying your code a bit, it seems to work. https://regexr.com/5s115

Comment: You might do it like that, but it will also match leading whitespace characters. Was the posted answer helpful?

Comment: yes it does that. Will need to evaluate further. Yes, the answer definitely helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a single space, you can use a 2 negative lookbehinds instead of a lookahead.

```
(?<!\bhome )(?<!\bparents )\b(?:flight|visit|travel)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AMNRmK/1)

If there can be multiple whitespace chars, you can capture the pattern that you want to keep, and use that in the replacement. What you want to replace, you can match (so not capture in a group)

For example using Python:

```
import re

strings = [
    "home   travel or home   visit or home    flight",
    "travel or visit or flight"
]
pattern = r"\b((?:home|parents)\s+(?:flight|visit|travel))\b|\b(?:flight|visit|travel)\b"
for s in strings:
    print(
        re.sub(
            pattern,
            lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else "[replacement here]",
            s
        )
    )
```

Output

```
home   travel or home   visit or home    flight
[replacement here] or [replacement here] or [replacement here]
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ni6fcl)